# Append multiple input text in one template

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, input, append

I have this code: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VtoCorleone/X4fDN/11/) And i want to make the same but instead of a textarea, an input type text (for title) and another input text (for description), and add all to this template:

```
<script id="template2" type="text/template">
  <li><div class="info3"><h3 id="b1"></h3><p> </p></div></li></script>
```

Where the input type text for title append to `<h3>`, and the input type text for description append to `<p>`

How can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use find like you did before:

```
templateHolder.find('h3').html($("#title").val());
templateHolder.find('p').html($("#description").val());
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X4fDN/22/) updated.